# While installing with Maven Tika I get errors related with LanguageProfile

Tags: maven, apache-tika

```
[ERROR] Unable to locate enclosing class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfile for nested class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfile$1
[ERROR] Unable to locate enclosing class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfile for nested class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfile$Counter
[ERROR] Unable to locate enclosing class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfile for nested class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfile$Interleaved
[ERROR] Unable to locate enclosing class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfilerBuilder for nested class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfilerBuilder$NGramEntry
[ERROR] Unable to locate enclosing class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfilerBuilder for nested class org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfilerBuilder$QuickStringBuffe
```

What is causing these errors and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Why are you trying to build Apache Tika from source? What's wrong with the pre-compiled binaries?

Comment: I want to get rid of these warning: 
WARNING: JBIG2ImageReader not loaded. jbig2 files will be ignored
See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
for optional dependencies.
TIFFImageWriter not loaded. tiff files will not be processed
See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
for optional dependencies.
J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed.
See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
for optional dependencies.

Comment: This one too: WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.

Comment: For the SQLite I actually tried the classpath param but for some reason it doesn't work. I added to my pom.xml and then did mvn install and it stille doesn't work. It's a bit annoying.

Comment: You don't need to rebuild Tika to fix those! Just grab the requisite jars (via maven or manually) and pop them on your runtime classpath

Comment: I did try. I tried this: `java -classpath /home/$USER/Projects/Lab/tika/classes/ -jar ./tika-app/target/tika-app-1.17.jar` and I still get: `WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.`. In the classpath dir I have: `sqlite-jdbc-3.19.3.jar` so even using classpath it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Java ignores `-classpath` if you specify `-jar`, so that'll never work! Java also won't load jars from a classes folder, so if the classes folder has the jars in then that won't work either.... You may need to follow some basic Java classpath tutorials first

Answer (score 0):

I see this when I build with Java 11 by accident, but it works with Java 8.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30546750)